# Regex - find all characters up to and including a string, replace with nothing in Google Sheets

Tags: regex, google-sheets

I'm working in Google Sheets. 
One column in my dataset has messy attribution data. 
I'm looking for a way to use Find + Replace to find all text up to and including certain words, like "by" and "attributed to", and replace them with nothing, leaving the rest of the string in the cell intact. I know this is very simple but I'm new to regular expressions; I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

I have never used Google Sheets, but the following find and replacement should work:

**Find:**

```
^.*attributed to(.*)$
```

**Replace:**

```
$1
```

This would assume you want to remove everything up to and including the last occurrence of the text `attributed to`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try `.+by|.+attributed to`.